# Como usar template para especializar uma função com o tipo char *?

Tags: c++, template

Estou fazendo exercícios de C++ e criei um template para a função de retornar o maior valor.

```
template<class Type>
Type maximo (const Type a, const Type b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
```

Agora a lista de exercícios pede para eu especializar a função para que funcione com o tipo char *, e dá o seguinte modelo:

```
template <>
Tipo funcao<Tipo>(Tipo param1, Tipo param2, ...) { ... }
```

Tipo é o tipo concreto a ser usado na especialização ( int , double , char * , etc.).

> Passo 6: (Desafio 1) Especialize a função maximo() para lidar com char
>   * usando a sintaxe acima. Use a função strcmp() ; será preciso incluir cstring . Faça modificações no main() para testar essas funções.
>   Compile e teste em seguida.

Porém não consigo fazer rodar. Minha função ficou:

```
template <>
char * maximo<char *>(const char *a, const char *b) {
    if (strcmp(a ,b) < 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe que na declaração do template, vc fez:

```
template<class Type>
Type maximo (const Type a, const Type b);
```

e agora quer especializar para `char *`. Então deve substituir `Type` por `char *`, ou seja

```
template <>
char * maximo(char *a, char *b);
```

Note que não tem o `const`. Se quiser substituir por `const char *`, tem que ficar:

```
template <>
const char * maximo(const char *a, const char *b);
```

ou seja, o tipo de retorno tem que ser `const char *`